# Simple effect tests on glmm significant interactions in R

Tags: r, glm

I have significant interactions in my glmm output and I know what my reference category (another interaction) is, but I need to know which variable is fixed when contrasting the significant interaction with the reference category.

I am looking for a post-hoc test called "simple effects test" (not Tukey). The same test is called "test slice" in JMP for any of you who use both R and JMP.

I have looked everywhere but cannot find the code for the simple effects test. Does anyone know how to use this test in R?

Here is an example of my glmm (using neg. binomial distribution) output:

```
Call:
glm.nb(formula = N ~ FoodCategory * Season + FoodCategory + Season + 
    (1 | Group/Animal), data = SPwg, init.theta = 0.8744631431, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.4796  -0.9720  -0.3713  -0.0350   4.7595  

Coefficients: (2 not defined because of singularities)
                                    Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)                           0.2763     0.2940   0.939  0.34748   
FoodCategoryFruit                     0.8849     0.3316   2.669  0.00762 **
FoodCategoryInvertebrate             -0.1962     0.5086  -0.386  0.69966   
FoodCategoryPlantMatter               0.4169     1.3153   0.317  0.75128   
SeasonHFLC                           -0.2250     0.4435  -0.507  0.61195   
SeasonLFLC                           -0.2763     0.4610  -0.599  0.54904   
1 | Group/AnimalTRUE                      NA         NA      NA       NA   
FoodCategoryFruit:SeasonHFLC          1.1511     0.4811   2.393  0.01673 * 
FoodCategoryInvertebrate:SeasonHFLC   1.6265     0.6784   2.398  0.01651 * 
FoodCategoryPlantMatter:SeasonHFLC        NA         NA      NA       NA   
FoodCategoryFruit:SeasonLFLC          1.5565     0.4997   3.115  0.00184 **
FoodCategoryInvertebrate:SeasonLFLC   0.3016     0.7822   0.386  0.69984   
FoodCategoryPlantMatter:SeasonLFLC    0.8640     1.4630   0.591  0.55479   
---
```

My reference category is "FoodCategoryOther:SeasonHFHL". I know from this output, for example, that "FoodCategoryFruit:SeasonLFLC" is significantly more positive than my reference category.

However, I do not know if this is because "FoodCategoryFruit" is significantly more positive than "FoodCategoryPlantMatter" during the "SeasonLFLC" (for example) or if "FoodCategoryFruit" is significantly more positive during the "SeasonLFLC" than "FoodCategoryFruit" is during the "SeasonHFHL".

A simple effects test will fix one of the variables while testing for the effects of the other. This is what I need to work out the problem, unless someone can inform me of a similar/better/more appropriate test. However, please don't tell me Tukey, because this post-hoc test does not fix one variable while testing for the effects of the other.

Comment: Were you talking about this: http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/r/faq/type3.htm

Comment: Actually, this is really a stats question rather than a programming question, and so better suited to CV. Too old to migrate now, though.

Answer (score 1):

This... is not a GLMM (generalized linear mixed model). You're fitting a regular old GLM with fixed effects only, albeit with the wrinkle of a negative binomial error distribution. Because `glm.nb` doesn't understand random effects notation, your `(1 | Group/Animal)` term has been interpreted as an arithmetic/logical expression, ie 1 ORed with the result of `Group` divided by `Animal`. 1 ORed with anything is identically TRUE, hence the NA coefficient for this term.

For an actual GLMM, you'll need to use something like `glmer` in the `lme4` package, or the `arm` package (and possibly others I don't know about).